# Is there an alternative to switching in a factory method?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, refactoring

I see this quite a lot and I was wondering if there was a way to refactor this nicely to avoid the massive switch?  This is a method in a factory: RoomControllerFactory,  instantiating a game location based on its type. Here's an example from a switch in the factory method:

```
            switch (location.getType())
            {
               case Location.ROOMONE:
                    return new RoomOneController(location, data, view);         

                case Location.ROOMTWO:
                    return new RoomTwoController(location, data, view);

                case Location.ROOMTHREE:
                    return new RoomThreeController(location, data, view);
```

Comment: I dont know actionscript but i would use a hashtable to register the types of the different locations with a RoomControllerFactory which inturn can instantiate the right RoomController. soooo in C# initially 
roomControllerFactories[location.getType()] = new RoomOneControllerFactory(); followed later by: roomControllerFactories[location.getType()].create(location,data,view);

Comment: Are these RoomController instances instantiated more than once in the program?  For example, if it were a maze, would you have multiple instances of TeeIntersectionRoomController?  Or are these instances absolutely unique in the game, for example BuckinghamPalaceThroneRoomController?  This *might* affect the best solution...

Comment: They exist at one time i.e when you go to the location, but are currently instantiated more than once, i.e if you go back to roomone we'll recreate room 1.  But also some rooms are unique some arn't, some rooms are abstract enough they can be used to represent more than one, for example a room type shop can be used for many locations different just by data- stuff for sale, but a room type own room will only be used once.  I hope thats clear. :)

Comment: Well I like to use ActionScript reflection in such cases:
`    var controllerClassName:String = "my.package." + location.getType() + "Controller";
    var controllerClass:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(controllerClassName));
    if (controllerClass) {
        var controllerInstance:IRoomController = new controllerClass(location, data, view);
        ...
    }
`.

Comment: This does have one drawback though ... As you are not directly referncing the Contoller Implementation classes, the compiler will not automatically include them in the generated SWF, so you have to explicitly include them.

Comment: I am wary of reflection because it is slow, but do you think is is justified in this situation?

Comment: I honestly think the original case-switch is superior to any solution that might involve ActionScript's half-assed "reflection" methods.  In a nutshell, I have seen people dive down some really bizarre rabbit holes trying to use it.  That way madness lies.  Stay on the OOP straight and narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, factories switch, that's what they do - the whole point of this style of factory is to centralise the construction logic into a single place rather than having it littered around the codebase.

As long as you are not using a Static Factory and coding to an IRoomControllerFactory interface then you get all the usual OOP benefits of swapping him out at runtime / for testing - after all you're saying 'Yo RoomControllerFactory, give me a room for this magic identifier!'

As a further answer to your question, you may want to ask yourself why you need so many concrete instances of RoomController?  Perhaps by favouring composition over inheritance you could refactor things to use a Builder instead?

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as you are using a hack to provide the enum functionality - why don't you add a method to your enum:

```
public static const ROOMONE : LocationType = new LocationType("locationone", 
    function(...) : RoomController { 
        return new RoomOneController
    }
);
```

(excuse any silly mistakes - actionscript isn't my first language!)

In java I would do similar with:

```
public enum LocationType {
    ROOMONE {
        @Override 
        public RoomController getRoomController() {
            return new RoomOneController();
        }
    };
    public abstract RoomController getRoomController();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that certainly seems like a cleaner solution, it reduces changes for adding a location to one place and the factory doesn't need to know about what its creating :)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this obviates the original "factory" completely, right?  Since the factory was just checking an enum value and spitting out a class instance, right?  I feel like I am missing something...

Comment: In this instance - yes.  But in a broader sense, there could be further implementation needed on the specific object returned which could warrant keeping the factory.

Comment: Yes it does, in the factory - using switch it is so tightly coupled to the enum you may as well put creation in the enum?  The only difference is you loose a bit of flexibility because you wouldn't usually subclass an enum whereas its common for a factory.

Comment: By moving the construction of the RoomController into the Enum you negate the need for a factory - but as a direct result it also means you bring all the dependencies of RoomController into the enum which doesn't strike me as a great solution. :(

Comment: It depends on your code - it's not the right solution for every case but if you can instantiate your object without any dependencies then it's good.  Agreed on your point if you have a load of things to pass in though.